# Gradle BuildType properties

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

What's the difference between these two properties of BuildType object (Gradle Android plugin)?  `applicationIdSuffix` and  `packageNameSuffix`?

And what does `zipAlign` property mean?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs about studio 0.6 and gradle build system, : http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio060released

> One of the user visible changes in 0.11 (gradle) is that we've deprecated the
>   `packageName` and `packageNameSuffix` settings, and have renamed them to
>   `applicationId` and `applicationIdSuffix`. The purpose of this is to make
>   it clear that this application id is decoupled from package
>   declarations in your manifest, and in particular, the `R class` and the
>   `BuildConfig class`, and all the implementation classes inside your app,
>   can be renamed and refactored freely; you just need to keep
>   applicationId the same. If you open your build.gradle file, lint is
>   highlighting these deprecated calls and offering quickfixes to update
>   them:

And zipalign http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html,

> is an archive alignment tool that provides important optimization to
>   Android application (.apk) files. The purpose is to ensure that all
>   uncompressed data starts with a particular alignment relative to the
>   start of the file. Specifically, it causes all uncompressed data
>   within the .apk, such as images or raw files, to be aligned on 4-byte
>   boundaries. This allows all portions to be accessed directly with
>   mmap() even if they contain binary data with alignment restrictions.
>   The benefit is a reduction in the amount of RAM consumed when running
>   the application.